# Is there a standard to manage permission in .Net

Tags: .net, permissions, identityserver4

Recently I started using IdentityServer4 in DotNet. It is recommended that IdentityServer should be used only for Identity and not for permissions. Is there a standard, like OAuth 2.0 or OpenID, for managing permissions? Is there a ubiquitous solution (like IdentityServer4) available for the DotNet platform to manage permissions (mainly for APIs, but also for web and native apps)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a built-in policy authorization in ASP.NET Core, that can allow you to get started with permissions. But if you have more advanced needs, the only option that I am aware of is [PolicyServer](https://policyserver.io/).

Here's some links to get started:

- https://policyserver.io/
- [Announcing PolicyServer](https://leastprivilege.com/2018/01/17/announcing-policyserver/)
- [Dominick Baier - Authorization for Modern Applications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dlrf85NTuAU&feature=youtu.be&ab_channel=DevConfPL)
- [PolicyServer (Commercial edition)](https://www.solliance.net/products/policyserver)